# What is the minimum number of cubes into which a cuboid of dimensions 4×4×7 can be divided?

Tags: geometry

What is the minimum.number of cubes into which a cuboid of dimensions 4×4×7 can be divided?
The side lengths of the cubes can be any positive real number, not necessarily integers. They can also be cut out of the cuboid in any way possible, the condition being that when you arrange said cubes, the resulting body is a 4×4×7 cuboid.

I have determined, albeit very naively, that the number of cubes is 21: we cut a cube of side length 4, then a 4×4×3 cuboid is left, from which we cut 4 cubes of side length 2 until a 1×4×4 cuboid is left, which we then divide into 16 cubes of side length 1. This totals to 21 cubes.

But I can't prove this is the minimum. When we consider that the cubes might also be cut along lines not perpendicular to the sides of the original cuboid, the conjecture is way over my head.

So is there any rigorous proof to my finding? Or is it false?

Comment: Please refrain from stating the question only in the title, and also add some details. What are the allowed ways to subdivide the cuboid? Must the resulting cubes have integer side lengths? And also please be more careful with the tags. I am not quite sure what the appropriate tags are, but algebraic geometry and numerical analysis are certainly not.

Comment: You can subdivide the cuboid any way you want to, but the result must be a group of cubes, and they have to cover the entire volume.